# How to estimate the total number of raffle tickets sold based on the serial of the ones that were drawn?

Tags: probability, statistics

Assume I'm playing in a raffle. The tickets are numbered uniquely and in sequence. So the first ticket has the serial number 1, the second has the serial number 2 and so on. At the end of the day someone draws 10 winning raffle tickets randomly. The winning serial numbers are public for everyone. For example:

`321,432,501,623,657,702,754,971,1101,1295`

Based on this information is there a way to estimate the total number of raffle tickets sold? Of course in this example we know that they sold at least 1295 ticket. But is there a method to find a probable estimate for the upper limit?

Comment: This is the German Tank Problem. See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/German_tank_problem

Comment: Yes, now that I know the name of the problem it answers my question.